# Sorting out what's true in the generic model in the classifying topos of a theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, intuition, topos-theory, categorical-logic

I'm interested in trying to understand the generic model in the classifying topos of a particular coherent theory$^1$, and more specifically trying to sort out what *non-coherent* formulae hold in said model. While I don't expect there to be a formulaic way to do this, it would be nice to see examples of something similar to orient myself. I may be wishing for something that doesn't exist here, but **I am looking for references (of any length) such that**:

1. the reference uses the machinery of classifying toposes
2. the focus is primarily on a particular coherent or geometric theory (as opposed to treatments in which the theory is an auxiliary device)
3. they specifically discuss features of the generic model (as opposed to being concerned only with the broad structure of the classifying topos).
4. Ideally, it does not lean heavily on prior knowledge that the theory is Morita equivalent to some non-syntactic site (though if the reference contains a proof of such an equivalence, that's great).

---

$^1$ I have omitted mention of the theory because I am confident there will be next to no literature on it (and no obvious non-syntactic site to which it is Morita equivalent).  But I can supply it if it would be helpful to answering this question for some reason.

Comment: Do you know about the paper "Classifying toposes for first-order theories" by Butz and Johnstone? In example 6.4 the work out the full (infinitary) first-order theory for the theory of objects. Of course, we know a particularly nice presentation of the corresponding classifying topos, but the technique used may be close enough to what you want.

Comment: @MarkKamsma - I will dig that up! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that [this draft of mine](https://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/paper-qcoh.pdf), to be finished soon, answers exactly your question. I value any feedback you might have!

Briefly (see Theorem 1.1), a formula holds of the generic model of $\mathbb{T}$ if and only if it is provable in intuitionistic logic from the axioms of $\mathbb{T}$ and the *Nullstellensatz*, a certain axiom scheme.

This is formulated in the context of geometric theories; the draft also contains a short remark (Scholium 3.14) about the coherent situation. The proof only uses the syntactic site, so fulfills your fourth criterion (and also the other three).

Comment: I will definitely give this a going over. Thanks!

Comment: A very boring question: when you write $\{\vec{x}.\alpha\}\vDash \varphi$, (e.g. on p.7), what version of $\vDash$ is intended? $\alpha\leq\varphi$ in the subobject lattice of $\prod_i X_i$ or some such?

Comment: Your question is not boring at all and will be adressed in the final version of these notes. The Kripke–Joyal semantics is intended (which you can learn about for instance in Section 7 of Mike Shulman's beautiful [notes on the stack semantics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3802) (don't worry, no knowledge of stacks is required)). But this amounts to exactly what you're saying, so feel free to think of that if you're more comfortable with it!

Comment: Oh, I just haven't seen $\vDash$ used for Kripke-Joyal stuff before. So the intended literal reading of the statement would be $よ\{\vec{x}.\alpha\}\Vdash\varphi$ in $\mathbf{Set}[\mathbb{T}]$, to use the more traditional forcing notation?

Comment: Yes, precisely. (I wasn't aware that the notation has been used that consistently, i.e. that ⊩ has always been used for forcing and that ⊨ has always been used for validity in Tarskian models. I didn't intend to change the notation.)

Comment: I may be overestimating the use of $\Vdash$; it's what I know from Mac Lane & Moerdijk, or Lambek & Scott, but there's been plenty of time for notation to move on since then...

Comment: I'm curious what is being expressed by "by passing to a covering," e.g. in the proofs of 3.5 and 3.6 (both theorems I would like to understand much better). I'm sure some perfectly standard fact about covers is being invoked, but I can't say I have any idea what (almost certainly due to my inexperience rather than your exposition).

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: Sorry for being terse! In general, what is meant is that instead of verifying $A \models \varphi$, we verify $A_i \models \varphi$ for all $i$, where $(A_i \to A)_i$ is a covering. For instance, in the case "$\bigvee$" in the proof of Lemma 3.5, $\alpha$ is of the form $\bigvee_i \beta_i$, and by definition of the syntactic site we have the covering $(\{ \vec x. \beta_i \} \to \{ \vec x. \alpha \})_i$. Hence it suffices to verify $\{ \vec x. \beta_i \} \models \underline{\mathbb{T}}/U_{\mathbb{T}}\  \mathrm{proves}\ (\top \vdash_{[]} \alpha)$. (continuing)

Comment: (continued) By induction hypothesis, we have $\{ \vec x. \beta_i \} \models \underline{\mathbb{T}}/U_{\mathbb{T}}\ \mathrm{proves}\ (\top \vdash_{[]} \beta_i)$. Since "$\underline{\mathbb{T}}/U_{\mathbb{T}}\ \mathrm{proves}\ (\top \vdash_{[]} \beta_i)$" intuitionistically entails "$\underline{\mathbb{T}}/U_{\mathbb{T}}\ \mathrm{proves}\ (\top \vdash_{[]} \alpha)$", we also have $\{ \vec x. \beta_i \} \models \underline{\mathbb{T}}/U_{\mathbb{T}}\ \mathrm{proves}\ (\top \vdash_{[]} \alpha)$ as desired. Is it clearer now? I'm happy to be of assistance!

Comment: Yes, that makes it clearer. Thanks for all your help!